# Given a DFA $\mathcal{M} = (S, \Sigma, q_0, \delta, F)$, is there an algorithm that finds the pumping length of $L(\mathcal{M}$)?

Tags: computer-science, formal-languages, automata

This question has been bugging me for a while, and I'm curious what such an algorithm would look like, if it exists. My guess is that it *does* exist, but I'm not sure how it would look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [proof of the pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_regular_languages#Proof_of_the_pumping_lemma), you’ll see that you can use for the pumping length $|S|$, the number of states in $\mathscr{M}$. There are [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFA_minimization) to reduce $\mathscr{M}$ to the minimal DFA accepting $L(\mathscr{M})$, if you want the best possible value.

Comment: Thanks very much, that makes sense.

Comment: @MrSinister13: You’re very welcome.